# Sorting and comparing XML from Java

Tags: java, xml, schema, nodes

I was given XML and schema files. My goal was to output all data from the XML (without duplicates) and order this list by the date of birth. Currently I got all data printed out (with duplicates) and I don't know what to do next. I've tried different things, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

After reading the post again I realised I need to remove dups too so:

You can use a `TreeSet` to impose unqiueness and sort by DOB - I presume that a person with the same first name, surname and date of birth is the same person.

First I would wrap your Node in a class that implements `Comparable` and that also does the getting of all those properties you have. The wrapper needs to implement `Comparable` as the `TreeSet` uses this method to decide whether elements are different (`a.compareTo(b) != 0`) and also how to order them.

```
public static final class NodeWrapper implements Comparable<NodeWrapper> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DOB_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private final Element element;
    private final Date dob;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String surName;
    private final String sex;

    public NodeWrapper(final Node node) {
        this.element = (Element) node;
        try {
            this.dob = DOB_FORMAT.parse(initDateOfBirth());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse dob", ex);
        }
        this.firstName = initFirstName();
        this.surName = initSurnameName();
        this.sex = initSex();
    }

    private String initFirstName() {
        return getNodeValue("firstname");
    }

    private String initSurnameName() {
        return getNodeValue("surname");
    }

    private String initDateOfBirth() {
        return getNodeValue("dateofbirth");
    }

    private String initSex() {
        return getNodeValue("sex");
    }

    private String getNodeValue(final String name) {
        return element.getElementsByTagName(name).item(0).getTextContent();
    }

    public Node getNode() {
        return element;
    }

    Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return DOB_FORMAT.format(dob);
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public int compareTo(NodeWrapper o) {
        int c;
        c = getDob().compareTo(o.getDob());
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
        c = getSurName().compareTo(o.getSurName());
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
        return getFirstName().compareTo(o.getFirstName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.dob != null ? this.dob.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.firstName != null ? this.firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.surName != null ? this.surName.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final NodeWrapper other = (NodeWrapper) obj;
        if (this.dob != other.dob && (this.dob == null || !this.dob.equals(other.dob))) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.firstName == null) ? (other.firstName != null) : !this.firstName.equals(other.firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.surName == null) ? (other.surName != null) : !this.surName.equals(other.surName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FirstName: " + getFirstName() + ". Surname: " + getSurName() + ". DOB: " + getDateOfBirth() + ". Sex: " + getSex() + ".";
    }
}
```

So if the date of birth, surname and firstname are all equal we assume it is the same person - we return 0.  It is good practice, if using `compareTo` in this way to make it **consistent with equals** so that if `a.compareTo(b)==0` then `a.equals(b)`, I have added the required `equals` and `hashCode` methods as well.

Now you can use a `TreeSet` in your code which will automatically sort and guarantee unqiueness:

```
final Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("file.xml"));

final Set<NodeWrapper> inimesteList = new TreeSet<NodeWrapper>();

final NodeList isa = doc.getElementsByTagName("isa");
for (int i = 0; i < isa.getLength(); i++) {
    inimesteList.add(new NodeWrapper(isa.item(i)));
}
final NodeList ema = doc.getElementsByTagName("ema");
for (int i = 0; i < ema.getLength(); i++) {
    inimesteList.add(new NodeWrapper(ema.item(i)));
}
final NodeList isik = doc.getElementsByTagName("isik");
for (int i = 0; i < isik.getLength(); i++) {
    inimesteList.add(new NodeWrapper(isik.item(i)));
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Total: " + inimesteList.size());

for (final NodeWrapper nw : inimesteList) {
    System.out.println(nw);
}
```

I have also added a `toString` method and used that to print the nodes - this makes the code much cleaner.

The `Document` approach, while seeming simpler than JAXB, is riddled with this sort of tedium. As you already have a schema I would **strongly recommend** that you make the move to `xjc` and JAXB unmarshalling - this will make this sort of stuff hundereds of times easier.

Comment: What is the type of your `Node` and `Element` - do you have the right imports? They should be, as in your snippet, from `org.w3c.dom`. Of course you cannot do `Element node = (Element) inimesteList.get(i)`. First of all if should not be a `List` but a `Set` so there is no `get` method. Secondly `NodeWrapper` is not a `Node`!! You need to get the wrapped `Node` using `getNode`.

Comment: That looks fine, what is `The constructor NodeWrapper(ode)...`, is this a typo? What is "ode"?

Comment: Where did you put the `NodeWrapper` class, in another class file? In which case check its imports.

Comment: Okay, that's perfect. I assume you removed the `static` modifier from the `class` definition in the `NodeWrapper.java`? I suspect the auto imports for new class are a bit wrong - they need to be the same as `harjutus.java`; i.e. all the imports need to be `com.w3c.dom`. Just edit your post and post up the new files.

Comment: What are trying to do with `Element node = (Element) inimesteList.get(i)`? You cannot get by id on a set. You need to use an [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: As I said **YOU NEED TO USE A TREESET** - please read and understand my code before commenting again.

Comment: Happy to help. But please pay slightly more attention to the answers people provide and try and _understand_ them before using them. Google is your friend and the javadocs for the core apis can be very helpful.

Comment: Post it as a separate question please. Explain what you have and then what you want the XML to look like.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` will depend on the `Node.equals()` method to determine equality, and you're adding *distinct* nodes, albeit with the same underlying text. From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no
>   element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))

I would extract the underlying text (`String`) from the `Node`, and a `HashSet<String>` will determine uniqueness correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create a Java Bean (POJO) with the single node details. Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in the same. Store all the Node data into the List of Bean. Then use `LinkedHashSet` to remove duplicates. Implement `Comparable` or use `Comparator` and `Collections.sort()` to sort the same.

---

Extend or encapsulate `Node` in another class and override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in the same. Store all the `Node`s into the `List` of new class instance. Then use `LinkedHashSet` to remove duplicates. Implement `Comparable` or use `Comparator` and `Collections.sort()` to sort the same.